# I Want to add different values using csv config in my following code

Tags: jmeter

In my below code i have to use multiple values in `userEmail`, `userName`, `userMobile`.
How can I do ti using csv config?

```
{"userDevicedId":"d0lfwViLwLQ:APA91bH4VSXS7VlthXhGQ4DPfb3otSUvwMnpmcK-mKyh7WN46xtDXWSYIOLB6Uw-nYr3zSBZOoiicpNuURQ2nR-a9vtwwSI8sehG-FbgYi4AaCdgurLG5C3Le4sYE0Lmp-piz_STLYnB","userEmail":"Tok@gmail.com","userMobileNo":"8989898995","userName":"Tik","userPasskey":"xmrVhb2MpmuzgLN941tGiLtdJnY3yvgMxlhXATEUa7SvsxclTiMLdJgPs7YTbNHF","userPassword":"Test123$$"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your CSV file looks like:

```
someone@example.com,someone,1234567890
someoneelse@example.com,someoneelse,2345678901
etc.
```

Configure CSV Data Set config as follows:

- Filename: full path to the CSV file
- Variable Names: `userEmail,userName,userMobile`
- Other config values - according to your scenario, see [Using CSV DATA SET CONFIG](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG) guide for detailed explanation

Refer extracted values like `${userEmail}`, `${userName}`, etc. where required, i.e. if you want to send parametrised JSON it should look like:

```
{
  "userDevicedId": "d0lfwViLwLQ:APA91bH4VSXS7VlthXhGQ4DPfb3otSUvwMnpmcK-mKyh7WN46xtDXWSYIOLB6Uw-nYr3zSBZOoiicpNuURQ2nR-a9vtwwSI8sehG-FbgYi4AaCdgurLG5C3Le4sYE0Lmp-piz_STLYnB",
  "userEmail": "${userEmail}",
  "userMobileNo": "${userMobile}",
  "userName": "${userName}",
  "userPasskey": "xmrVhb2MpmuzgLN941tGiLtdJnY3yvgMxlhXATEUa7SvsxclTiMLdJgPs7YTbNHF",
  "userPassword": "Test123$$"
}
```

- If you're using [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler, switch it to "Body Data" mode:

  [image: HTTP Body Data]
- Remember that CSV Data Set config reads next line each iteration so make sure you provide enough loops on [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) level or via [Loop Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller)